# Java 8 stream: periodic sum on array

Tags: java, arrays, indexing, sum, java-stream

I want to do a periodic sum on an array, i.e. a sum over index modulo n.

```
int size=100;
double[] doubleArr = new double[size];
for (int i = 0; i < size; i++){
    doubleArr[i]=Math.random();
}
int n=2;
double[] results= new double[n];
for (int i = 0; i < doubleArr.length; i++) {
    results[i % n] += doubleArr[i];
}
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(results));
```

This code works, but as my arrays are very huge, I want to parallelize the operation.

The Java 8 stream seems to be a good solution.

```
double[] results2= new double[n];
IntStream.range(0, doubleArr.length).forEach(i -> results2[i % n] += doubleArr[i]);
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(results2));
```

I get the same result. Fine.

But if I want parallelize, it fails.

```
double[] results3= new double[n];
IntStream.range(0, doubleArr.length).parallel().forEach(i ->     results3[i % n] += doubleArr[i]);
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(results3));
```

I understand it's because results3 is mutable.

I guess I should produce the results inside the stream operation, with a collect, but I don't find how to proceed.

Comment: It fails with an exception or how? If an exception is thrown post it the exception, if the result is not what is expected post the result and the expectations

Comment: What do you mean by "it fails"?

Comment: @REACHUS The final array is edited from multiple threads, this gives inaccurate results

Comment: Right, results are inaccurates e.g.
results [21.860094470094793, 21.53562534144981]
results2 [21.860094470094793, 21.53562534144981]
results3 [21.69682132149239, 20.755094007057508]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can start from range of possible modulos (0..n):

```
double[] result = IntStream.range(0, n)
         .mapToDouble(i -> IntStream.rangeClosed(0, (size-i-1)/n)
                                    .mapToDouble(j -> doubleArr[j*n+i]).sum())
         .toArray();
```

If `n` is more that number of cores you have, then paralleling the outer stream would be enough. If not, try to parallelize the inner stream.

Comment: but it's slower than the basic loop :'(

Comment: @xehyrofidd, in parallel for `size = 1_000_000` it's faster for me (though speedup is not very significant). Btw, if you don't need Kahan summation replace `.sum()` with `.reduce(0, Double::sum)`, it will be faster.

Comment: yes it's faster for  little value of n compared to size. But in case of n=size/50, it's not anymore.

Comment: @xehyrofidd, it's also quite possible that you measure speed incorrectly.